# javascript not linking correctly with HTML. how to fix?

Tags: javascript, html

here's my HTML

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />        
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>
```

....

and here's the javascript. everything was fine when i had the script inline, but when i move it outside of the html file it breaks. just a simple html canvas drawing but not sure the issue. ideas?

```
// Canvas 1

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

photo = document.getElementById("red");

function drawImage() {
context.drawImage(photo, 0, 0);
}

window.addEventListener("load", drawImage, false);

// Canvas 2
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");

context2.fillStyle = "darkRed"; 
context2.fillRect(0, 2, 800, 500);
context2.moveTo(0, 0);
context2.lineTo(400, 300);


// Canvas 3 

var canvas3 = document.getElementById("canvas3");
var context3 = canvas3.getContext("2d");

photo3 = document.getElementById("red2");

function drawImage() {
    for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        for (var y =0; y < 6; y++ ) {
            context3.drawImage(photo3, x * 100, y * 75, 100, 75);
        }
    }

}

window.addEventListener("load", drawImage, false);
```

Comment: Is `script.js` in the same directory as your HTML file? Does your browser's debugger have any JavaScript errors or say anything about failing to load the script?

Comment: @mason yes to file name and I'm getting: "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'canvas.getContext')"

Comment: you have two functions named exactly the same thing (drawImage), just bad javascript. Also if this script runs in the head, the very first line will fail as the html has not even rendered yet, so nothing there yet to getById, wrap this whole code in a DOMLoaded event or put it a the bottom of the html page, so all the HTML elements are there ready to be accessed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're loading the script in the `<head>`, everything is running before the DOM is loaded, so all your `getElementBuId()` calls are failing. You either need to put the `<script>` tag at the end of the `<body>`, or put all the code into a `window.onload` function, e.g.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    photo = document.getElementById("red");

    function drawImage() {
        context.drawImage(photo, 0, 0);
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", drawImage, false);
    ...
};
```

This has the added benefit of not polluting the global namespace.

Comment: thanks! that fixed most of it. still have this error though: "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'canvas.getContext')"

Comment: Then there must not be an element with `id="canvas1"` in the document. Check for a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second what Barmar said. In general, I load my JavaScript at the end of the html for better performance, and so I'm sure I won't have this issue.